# A Database is connected but select query doesn't work?

Tags: php, database

My database is on dream host. And its unable to connect .
 MY code is

```
<?php
    $hostname = "mysql.demos.smartmobe.com";   // eg. mysql.yourdomain.com (unique)
    $username = "nayacinema";   // the username specified when setting-up the database
    $password = "****";   // the password specified when setting-up the database
    $database = "nayacinema";   // the database name chosen when setting-up the database (unique)



    $con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$databse);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        echo 'done';
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM TblUsers");
    print_r($result);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
        echo "<br>";
    }

?>
```

it gives error like this

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/demo_smartmobe/demos.smartmobe.com/nayacinema/test.php on line 20
```

what may be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide us some more code?

Comment: Use `echo mysqli_error($con);` after `mysqli_query` . It shows if any errors found when executing queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake.

`$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$databse);`

Should be

`$con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);`

(*database* spelt wrong)

Answer (score 0):

i have tested your code there was no connectivity.. because of spelling mistake here is correct code , i have tested on my local machine

```
<?php
    $hostname = "localhost";   // eg. mysql.yourdomain.com (unique)
    $username = "root";   // the username specified when setting-up the database
    $password = "";   // the password specified when setting-up the database
    $database = "test";   // the database name chosen when setting-up the database (unique)



    $con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        echo 'done';
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user");
    print_r($result);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['user_name'];
        echo "<br>";
    }

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: this is not the ansewr..